# CSS Resolution Media Query Support

Tags: css, resolution, media-queries, dpi, liquid-layout

Currently, only Firefox and Internet Explorer (!) seem to have support for the `min-resolution` and `max-resolution` CSS media queries (see [here](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/@media_%28min-resolution%29) and [here](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%40media_%28max-resolution%29)). When can we expect support for these media queries in Webkit browsers? In particular, which versions of Chrome and Safari will have support for them? If the queries are not supported in the development builds, is support for them planned? It is sadly ironic that Safari on the Macbook Pro with Retina Display does not yet support this query.

Thanks for the help!